# Escaping a single quote in a variable before Insert

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

Here's how my insert code looks:

```
$values .= ($ta->account_toll_free_number != '') ? ",('" . $post_id . "', 'toll_free_number','" . $ta->account_toll_free_number . "')" : NULL;
```

Which gives me:

```
(111, 'toll_free_number', '888-123-1234')
```

Which works great until there is a single quote mark in the variable. Then it breaks. Is there someway I can clean/escape it before this? Do I just need to swap my single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: Use PDO and prepared statement - no need for any escaping.

Comment: What is the benefit of using the ternary operator here?

Comment: It's for an import script from an older custom CMS to Wordpress. This is just one example I have about 500 custom fields I'm going through. There's no harm from SQL injection as this script is only ran on the production site once. I have full control over what's going in it.

Comment: PDO prepared statement handle all quoting... this is not only benificiary for SQL injections, it's just safer for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way.
I just started with your output and added a single quote for last part.

```
  $values = mysql_real_escape_string("(111, 'toll_free_number', '888-'123-1234')");
  $query = "INSERT INTO yourtable (fieldname) values ('".$values."')";
  mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

see more from manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter pointed out, I would recommend you use PDO as this is an escaping issue and opens you up to SQL injection vulnerabilities.  On the change that you are using mysql_* instead, try escaping the variable with mysql_real_escape_string() first.

Comment: I'm actually not worried about SQL injections this is an import script that I have full control over and won't be on the live server.

Comment: Once again though, if you are using mysql_* you should escape your input as it will fail on quotes and other special characters.  Use mysql_real_escape_string()